# Possible to have a cloud primary mailbox with an on-prem archive mailbox?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, microsoft-office-365, entra-id, exchange-hybrid

I have a customer that wants to migrate their users  primary mailboxes from Exchange 2016 to Office 365-Exchange Online but leave their archive mailboxes on-prem.

I haven't been able to decipher what little I've found on this topic into a clear answer. Anyone know for certain whether this is a supported scenario?

To be clear this customer has not yet migrated, when they do they will be syncing AD and in a Hybrid relationship.

Thanks in advance for help!!!

Comment: What is the benefit here? The user need to pay then for two licenses (Exchange Online and On-Premises).

Answer (score 0):

No, it is only possible to do this the other way around.

Options:

- Your mailbox can be on-prem with an archive on-prem
- Your mailbox can be on-prem with an archive in Exchange Online
- Your mailbox can be in Exchange Online and also your archive can be
  in Exchange Online

ref:

- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rmilne/2015/04/30/enable-remote-archive-with-exchange-hybrid/
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt791517(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Is this answer wrong?  I note its been downvoted, but it seems to be the only answer.